# how can i get response from json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

Making my login screen in flutter for first time and i have tried many ways to parse json but none of worked till now. can anyone please help me to get response from json so i can also get idea about this.

```
---my model class

class User{
  String email;
  String password;
  String token;

  User({
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.token
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
   // Map json = parsedJson['user'];
    return User(
        email: parsedJson['email'],
       password: parsedJson['password'],
       token: parsedJson['token']
      );
  }
}


-------
json for response.

Future loadUser() async{
   final response = await  http.get(url, headers : { 
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'
  }
  body : User.fromJson(response);
  print(user.token);
   );


    enter code here

}
-----

{
    "email": "zxc@example.com",
    "password": "aa718893bfe3e587047c81af40269d14",
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6Mn0.MGBf"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can parse your JSON string with

```
final user = userFromJson(jsonString);
```

or convert your user object to json string with userToJson function

User class code

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final user = userFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
    String email;
    String password;
    String token;

    User({
        this.email,
        this.password,
        this.token,
    });

    factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new User(
        email: json["email"],
        password: json["password"],
        token: json["token"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "token": token,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Flutter's official http package to perform GET and POST operations.

https://pub.dev/packages/http

To install the `http` package, add it to the dependencies section of the `pubspec.yaml`. You can find the latest version of the `http` package on the Pub site.

```
dependencies:
  http: <latest_version>
```

To perform GET operation call http.get(),

```
http.get("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=api").then(
  (response) // Server response
    {
      if(response.statusCode==200) // Checking if the transaction was successful
        {
          print(response.body);// Your response body
        }
       else print("The transaction was unsuccessful");
    }
);
```

> If you want to parse your json request,
>
> https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Reference : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 1):

```
Future loadUser() async{

    final response = await  http.get(url, 
        headers : { HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json' }
        Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson = json.decode(response.body);
        body : User.fromJson(parsedJson); 
    );
}
```